# Access adb screenshots/screencast on rooted honeycomb tablet?

Tags: android, api, screenshot, root

is there a way to access adb screenshots on a rooted Honeycomb tablet?
Is there something like an api to get a snapshot?
The perfect way would be a video recoding app.

Unfortunately "Screencast Video Recorder" fails to recode on my device, since I have a Tegra 2 chipset.